# Is there a way to use the fetch event listener in a serviceworker created in a Violentmonkey script?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, tampermonkey, userscripts

For a userscript, I need code that caches an Audio file upon fetch and replaces a request on a re-fetch, however I couldn't find a way to register a serviceworker under a userscript that can intercept fetch requests. If I create a worker through

```js
var blob = new Blob(["self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {console.log('Intercepted request:', event.request.url);});"
],{type: 'text/javascript'});

var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

It registers the worker but the fetch event does not trigger on fetch events on the page. Is there a way to circumvent this behaviour? I cannot use `navigator.serviceworker.register` as it requires a URL relative to base URL.

Comment: Just a consideration: service workers might not be the ideal solution — [only one can be registered per scope](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/service-workers/), so if the site already registers one, your registration might conflict

Comment: The only way (intentionally, by design) to register a service worker is to use a script on that site's URL. You can disable navigator.serviceWorker (after unregistering the existing worker) in a script running at `document-start` altogether to prevent the site from using it.